# bxslider IE Issues , Images stacked vertically

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slideshow, bxslider

I am currently re creating my portfolio page , It is a work in progress...
On my home page I have a bxslider from bxslider.com , it works in all other browsers but on IE , it has no transitions and just simply stacks the images on top of each other...

The page can be viewed [here](http://www.jn-design.co.uk/redesign2)

CSS as follows:

```
#slides
{
width:100%;
height:400px;
margin-top:150px;
background-image:url('low_contrast_linen.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
z-index:-3;
border-bottom: 4px solid #ff7373;   
}

#slideshowwrap
{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:900px;
 height:250px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 z-index:-3;    
 }

#slider1
{
 width:1300px;
 height:300px;
 position: fixed;
}
```

HTML as follows:

```
<div id="slides">
    Slideshow goes here (Full Width)
    <div id="slideshowwrap">
        <div id="slider1">
            <div> <img src="slideone.png" alt="slide one"/> </div>
            <div><img src="slidetwo.png" alt="slide two"/></div>
            <div> <img src="slidethree.png" alt="slide three" /> </div>
            <div><img src="slidefour.png" alt="slide four"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put bnxslider code in jquery ready function?

Comment: Sorry how do you mean? Im quite a novice when it comes to Jquery etc...

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ $('#slider1').bxSlider({
      auto: true,
     pause:10000,
     controls:false,
     speed:5000
    });
});

Comment: Thanks but no that does not work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create on your root server folder a new javascript file and call it bxSlider.min.js .
Copy/Paste in it content of https://raw.github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/master/jquery.bxSlider.min.js

Replace in your code:

```
 <script src="https://raw.github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/master/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

by (assuming you put your freshly created script file in same folder as your index.html):

```
<script src="bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See now whats going on...

Comment: Just tried that , uploaded it aswell, but no joy! , can you check I have put it in the right location please...

Comment: And if you insert bxSlider script directly in your page, just before $(document).ready(function(), whats going on? Because i think internet explorer could block you injected script from https github.

Comment: So how do I go about solving it...?

Comment: I see by debugging under ie9 SEC7112 error, thats means that github server is sending an X-Content-Type-Options. So your script is not properly interpreted. Ill updated my answer to show you how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks alot! Works perfectly , any reason to why this happened? IE simply not allowing it to run?

Comment: Ya, for security reason. Other browsers seem to ignore this kind of failure.